# MySQL Procedure Update Unique Column if value exists return 0 otherwise return 1

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-key

I have a table which have one primary key (phone_number), one unique column (nick).

I want to write a procedure which gets phone_number and nick as input. It will update nick of row that if phone_number = in_phone_number. If nick already exists in another row I want to return an output parameter 0, otherwise update and return 1.

Can I do it with one query? Something like this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET nick = in_nick where phone_number = in_phone_number
ON DUPLICATE KEY SET result = 0 otherwise SET result = 1;
```

Comment: Could you post an example of a situation where you'd have a "nick in another row"? I would think that this couldn't happen if the column were unique.

Comment: It is unique and one row has the value that I try to update. For example

phone_number = "1" nick = "a"
phone_number = "2" nick = "b"

If I write this
UPDATE my_table SET nick = "b" where phone_number = "1";